# jQuery doesn't select lineargradient object

Tags: jquery, dom, svg, jquery-1.3.2

I am using jQuery 1.3.2, and I'm trying to select some elements in an svg DOM element.

```
$('svg > defs > lineargradient')
```

However for some reason it does not select it, I know that I can access other items in the <svg> element since I have successfully retrieved an $("svg > rect").

My SVG DOM looks like this:

```
<svg width="975" height="385">
    <defs>
       <lineargradient id="raphael-gradient-0" x1="1.000" y1="1.000" x2="0.000" y2="0.000">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#242b62"/><stop offset="9.090909090909092%" stop-color="#174a88"/>
          <stop offset="18.181818181818183%" stop-color="#0e60a3"/><stop offset="27.272727272727273%" stop-color="#0b66ab"/>
          <stop offset="36.36363636363637%" stop-color="#0870b7"/>
       ...
       </lineargradient>
       <lineargradient id="raphael-gradient-1" x1="1.000" y1="1.000" x2="0.000" y2="0.000">...</lineargradient>

    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="40" r="10" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000" transform=""/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="975" height="385" fill="url(#raphael-gradient-1)" stroke="none" transform="" style="opacity: 1;" opacity="1" fill-opacity="1"/>
</svg>
```

Is there any reason why jQuery 1.3.2 wouldn't be able to select the <lineargradient> elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($('svg lineargradient').length);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/avoti)**

**EDIT:**

It appears that the `>` immediate child expression does not work, but if you specify a selector without this (if possible), it is fine in Firefox (but **not** IE). The following does work in IE however (tested in IE7)

```
alert($('lineargradient').length);
```

obviously, this will selecting the `<lineargradient>` elements that you want on a page slightly harder, but commands like `slice()` and `eq()` will allow you to get to them by position in the wrapped set.

Writing your own filters for the [Sizzle](http://wiki.github.com/jeresig/sizzle) selector engine may yield the results you want.

Comment: It says the number of "linear gradients is 0" on IE8.

Comment: @leeand00 - that's twice in the last week I've been caught out by not testing on IE (tend to use Firefox). It's to do with the Sizzle Selector engine that jQuery uses.

Comment: @leeand00 - specifying just $('lineargradient') works in IE7, but that makes it slightly trickier if you have lots of those elements on the page.

Comment: @Russ Yeah that happens to me alot too...I think it's a geeks natural tendency to reduce complexity.  (which IE never does...)